# Can shared public images or community images be region specific like private images do in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, cloud, amazon-ami

Private images in AWS are region specific. Are shared public images or community images also region specific?

Edit: What about the case with GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand all AMI's in AWS are region specific. For example, if you use Ubuntu or CentOS public images, then they are region scoped, you can't use them outside the regions you've accepted the T's & C's for, until you subscribe to the image for a different region.

To summarise.

Yes, Public Images and Community Images are also region specific.

Comment: Does the same hold true for GCP as well?

Comment: I'd love to be able to answer that, but unfortunately I have no experience with GCP!

Answer (score 1):

GCP images are global resources... They are not associated with a region or zone

Comment: Even the private images?

Comment: That's correct...  Images created in GCP are available to all regions and zones.

Answer (score 0):

As par Amazon,

*AMIs are a regional resource. Therefore, sharing an AMI makes it available in that region. To make an AMI available in a different region, copy the AMI to the region and then share it.*

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html

i.e. any AMI be it private or public, it is region specific.